# CSFML with VS Code and MSVC cl.exe LNK2019 error

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, sfml

So I'm brand new to the C language and have started taking a look at CSFML and have run into an issue when trying to compile in VS Code this is my tasks.json:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/Fe:",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "${file}",
                "-I${fileDirname}\\CSFML-2.5-windows-64-bit\\include",
                "-L${fileDirname}\\CSFML-2.5-windows-64-bit\\lib\\msvc"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

this is my launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "cl.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is some simple code I'm trying to run to just make a window:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /*24 bit colour depth at 800 by 600 resolution*/
    sfVideoMode mode = {800, 600, 24};
    sfRenderWindow *window;
    /*This will be used in the main loop*/
    sfEvent event;
    /*Start creating the window*/
    window = sfRenderWindow_create(mode, "SFML Test", sfResize | sfClose, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        puts("Unable to create window, aborting.");
        return 1;
    }

    /*Main loop*/
    while (sfRenderWindow_isOpen(window))
    {
        /*This processes the event que*/

        while (sfRenderWindow_pollEvent(window, &event))
        {
            if (event.type == sfEvtClosed)
            {
                puts("Closing render window.");
                sfRenderWindow_close(window);
            }
        }
    }
    /*Cleanup*/
    sfRenderWindow_destroy(window);
    return 0;
}
}
```

but if attempt to run the program I get the following:

```
> Executing task: C/C++: cl.exe build active file <

Starting build...
Build finished with errors(s):
main.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29333.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/debug 
"/out:C:\Users\Student\OneDrive - Liverpool Hope University\Year 1\Core 2\Guide to Assessments and Policies\Coursework\4-in-a-row\main.exe" 
main.obj 
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__sfRenderWindow_create referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__sfRenderWindow_destroy referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__sfRenderWindow_close referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__sfRenderWindow_isOpen referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__sfRenderWindow_pollEvent referenced in function _main
C:\Users\Student\OneDrive - Liverpool Hope University\Year 1\Core 2\Guide to Assessments and Policies\Coursework\4-in-a-row\main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals

The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

As I said I'm very new to C so I'm not really sure what's going on my guess is that the dll's in the CSFML folder need to also be loaded some how but I really don't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after many hours of trying to work it out and googling and stackoverflow and discord servers I finally managed to figure it out...

I found the correct commandline args and order but kept having issues as it wouldn't compile for 64 bit but would for x86/32 bit

Since I'm using MSVC the you have to launch VS Code using "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019" and well turns out that that defaults to an x86 build environment which isn't said in any of the documentation but if u open "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019" instead and open code using that it works using the following tasks.json:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/I${fileDirname}/CSFML-2.5-windows-64-bit/include",
                "${fileDirname}\\CSFML-2.5-windows-64-bit\\lib\\msvc\\csfml-graphics.lib",
                "${file}",
                "/link",
                "/MACHINE:x64",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this solution - I was ready to pull my hair out over this exact problem! So, anyone who's following [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) on how to set up VS Code for C/C++ on Windows, if you're running into this issue, then you may just have to ignore where it says "(...) you must run from a Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio", and use an x64 prompt, as explained above.

Comment: To add some background info for those puzzled by this issue: Those "unresolved external symbol" errors are raised by the linker, not the compiler. As long as you just compile a few self-contained C/C++ source files (perhaps some "Hello World" tutorial), it often won't matter whether you build for a 32 or a 64-bit architecture. Either will do. But in my case, the linker needed to link against an external library, and that library was build for 64-bit. However, I was building for 32-bit, hence the error.